# Mass update Excel file connection string

Tags: sql, string, excel, connection

We have recently changed our SQL Database server and i was wondering if there would be a script or an easier method of updating all the Excel file connection strings?

It would of been alot easier if they used a connection file but unfortunately they were all set manually and we have about 600 reports...

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: You can use the `Workbook.Connections` collection to loop over all connections in a workbook

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the exact same thing and came accross this tool called `XLODCTool` from [here](https://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/office-data-connection-bulk-editor-tool/).

File link [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=53E1D37F76F69444!911&authkey=!AAXddOwbRbNiu9I&ithint=folder%2C.zip).

Allos you to bulk change values inside of a connection string e.g.

`DSN` From `SERVERA` to `SERVERB`

Comment: This is best answer given since it does not involve any custom vba code and can be easily&quickly executed from stand-alone utility!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can... you make a program in c# or vb.net that loops throu all of your 600 documents and opens the documents and by using

```
    oModule = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
    oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)
```

and depending on your setup in the sCode variable you have a macro that loops through Excel.Connections or

```
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
        With qt
          .Connection ="myconnstring" 
        End With
      Next qt
    Next wks
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Archlight solution, the macro is the following :

```
Sub UpdateConnectionsString_Click()
   For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
          With qt
           'Debug.Print .Connection
           .Connection = Replace(.Connection, "bla.com", "localhost")
          End With
      Next qt
    Next wks
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell script loops through all xlsx files in the current directory.
Extracts them, and then does a find and replace in the connection strings file.
Adds the files back into a new archive(xlsx file) with the same name. Suffixed with '_new'

Copy paste into a *.ps1 file and run.

```
echo `nStarting....`n
$Zips = Get-ChildItem -filter "*.xlsx" -Recurse
$Destination = 'Extracted/'
$WinRar = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\winrar.exe"

foreach ($zip in $Zips)
{
$des = $Destination + $zip.BaseName + "/"
&$Winrar x -Y -ibck $zip.FullName $des
Get-Process winrar | Wait-Process

}

$configFiles = Get-ChildItem Extracted\*\xl\connections.xml -recurse 
$configFiles | Set-ItemProperty -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false

foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "SERVER=123456;", "SERVER=7891011;" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath

}

$configFiles = Get-ChildItem Extracted | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}

foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    $FileDestination = './' + $file.Name + '_new.xlsx'
    $files = 'Extracted/' + $file.Name + '/*.*'
    &$Winrar a -r -afzip -ep1 $FileDestination $files
}

echo `nDone!`n
```