# Publish an Excel 2013 OData data connection file (odc) using GPO WITHOUT sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, gpo

This is quite a specific request for help.

We have trying to give all our excel users a single workbook connection to an OData which is centrally managed (so we can update it in future, and to stop users adapting it).

Ideally we could publish this out using GPO and have it show up in the "Connection on your network" section of the connections within Excel. We can publish the .odc file to all computers but that would require all users to update the connection manually, which we are trying to avoid.
We have recently decommissioned our sharepoint server so that's not an option.

We attempted a registry change as listed here https://martinmason.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/excel-2010-connection-files-on-the-network-sharepoint-data-connection-libraries-and-the-enterprise/
but couldn't get it to accept a network location.

And we can't possibly know all the workbooks connected so can't do a VBA/Powershell update on the connection string as mentioned here [Mass update Excel file connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732033/mass-update-excel-file-connection-string)

It seems to be the exact same question asked here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/932aa489-6b6f-4de3-9935-f4d8748eea84/excel-2010-data-connection-files-odc-on-a-network-folder?forum=excel but the response still involved sharepoint...

Any help would be greatly appreciated