# Updating thousands of excel data connection strings

Tags: python, excel, vba, business-intelligence

I have a lot of excel files, each with an odbc data connection string. However we're changing our server connection so these all need to be changed. Does anyone know if there is an efficient way to do this over thousands of excel files?

Perhaps there is a solution using python or VBA?

Comment: You can convert them all to .csv files, then write a python program to automatically load each .csv file into a pandas DataFrame, make the selective edit needed, write that back to the .csv file, then convert each .csv file back into a .xls file. Note you can use something like ```copy *.xls output.csv``` in Windows for the first step, or with Linux use the python module csvkit for this.

Comment: Would the .csv files imported into pandas still have their external data connection string though?

Comment: If that data connection string is not stored in one of the spreadsheet cells, then no. The Excel docs state "Connection information is stored in the workbook and can also be stored in a connection file, such as an Office Data Connection (ODC) file (.odc) or a Data Source Name file (.dsn)."  Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mass update Excel file connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732033/mass-update-excel-file-connection-string)